# Not able to use at the same time "createStackNavigator and createDrawerNavigator"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

hope you are doing great. I just started learning react-native and everything seems good. I am pretty new to JSX so Im hoping somebody can guide me on the right path on this question in which I havent beeen able to find a correct answer on Google.

I have been trying to use at the same time "createStackNavigator and createDrawerNavigator" from "react-native" and "react-navigation" but I am not able to make it work at the same time. The buttons and the menu on the header disappear.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; // 1.0.0-beta.27

class LogoTitle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Image
        source={require('./assets/spiro.png')}
        style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
      />
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawerMenu extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: <LogoTitle />,
    drawerLabel: 'Home',
    headerLeft:
    <View>
    <Button
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')}
      title="Menu"
       />
    </View>,
    headerRight: (
    <View>
      <Button
        onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
        title="Info"
        color="#fff"
      />
    </View>
    ),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
             onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')}
             title="Open Drawer"
           />
    );
  }
}

class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
             onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')}
             title="Open Drawer"
           />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  },
});

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  MyDrawerMenu: {
    screen: MyDrawerMenu,
  },
});

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MyHomeScreen: {
      screen: MyHomeScreen,
    },
    MyDrawerNavigator: {
      screen: MyDrawerNavigator,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'MyHomeScreen',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#333',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    },
  }
);

const MyApp = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyApp />
    );
  }
}
```

If you guys see the problem I please guide me through. Thank you very much,

Sincerely,

Comment: What do you mean by **trying to use at the same time "createStackNavigator and createDrawerNavigator"** ? What do you really want to achieve ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your follow up, Suraj I appreciate it. I was trying to make the drawer menu work but I already got it. I dont now how I was able but now it is working. I will keep up reading and learmning. Appreciate it.